# Unable to load data after changing the data-url in bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

Using [bootstrap-table](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/export.html) I am trying to replicate similar solution.
I just tried replacing the `data-url` where it stopped working. I like to use my own URL with  JSON data such as https://jsonkeeper.com/b/A4MR
PS-Newbie to bootstrap-table and never used before.

```html
<html>

<body class="container">

  <h2><i class="bi bi-cart"></i> List Generator</h2>


  <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@10.7.2/styles/default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hint.css@2.6.0/hint.min.css">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/tableExport.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/libs/jsPDF-AutoTable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.2/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sprintf-js@1.1.2/dist/sprintf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@10.7.2/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@3.0.8/marked.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/flexibility@2.0.1/flexibility.js"></script>

  <style>
    #toolbar {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="toolbar" class="select">
    <select class="form-control">
      <!-- <option value="">Export Basic</option> -->
      <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
      <option value="all">Export All</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <table id="table" data-show-export="true" data-pagination="true" data-side-pagination="client" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="false" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-show-columns="false" data-search="true" data-toggle="table" data-maintain-meta-data="true"
    data-url="https://jsonkeeper.com/b/A4MR">

  </table>

  <!-- data-url= "https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data">-->
  <!-- data-url="https://jsonkeeper.com/b/A4MR"> -->

  <script>
    var $table = $('#table')

    $(function() {
      $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function() {
        $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
          exportDataType: $(this).val(),
          //  exportTypes: ['json', 'xml','csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf'],
          exportTypes: ['txt', 'pdf', '', '', '', ''],
          columns: [{
              field: 'state',
              checkbox: true,
              visible: $(this).val() === 'selected'
            },
            {
              field: 'id',
              title: 'ID'
            }, {
              field: 'name',
              title: 'Item Name'
            }, {
              field: 'price',
              title: 'Item Price'
            }
          ]
        })
      }).trigger('change')
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The request is blocked by CORS, [jsonkeeper.com](https://jsonkeeper.com) don't send the `cors` header. That means the browser will stop the request.
For example https://api.npoint.io/1bf6801f5389b3e440bb would work, because they set the `cors` header(s) e.g. `access-control-allow-origin: *` 
Credits to this answer goes to Bootstrap-table issues at Git.